# How to enable copy/paste on a VM-Ware virtual Windows machine?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation, clipboard

I've just created a virtual Windows-10 machine, but the virtual machine settings don't mention any isolation-related entries, so what can I do in order to enable copy/paste on that virtual machine?

More information:

VMWare Workstation 17 Player, Version 17.0.1 build-21139696

Virtual Machine settings ("Options" tag):

[image]

Comment: The UI to control guest isolation settings are available only in VMware Workstation Pro. 
 However, copy/paste should be enabled by default.  Did you install VMware Tools in the VM?

Comment: No. How should I do that?

Comment: Power on the VM, and from the menubar, choose Player > Manage > Install VMware Tools.